# SELECT ... ORDER BY field IN (SELECT ...) not working on duplicate field

Tags: mysql, sorting

I need to sort a MySQL table after two columns, but not like a regular sort. In a chat application i want to get results sorted by timestamp field, but also grouped by their sender

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  timestamp timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  sender int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  message char(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('1', '2011-02-28 01:58:24', '3', '1');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('2', '2011-02-28 01:58:28', '3', '2');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('3', '2011-02-28 01:58:35', '1', '5');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('4', '2011-02-28 01:58:36', '2', '7');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('5', '2011-02-28 01:58:38', '3', '3');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('6', '2011-02-28 01:58:39', '2', '8');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('7', '2011-02-28 01:58:40', '1', '6');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES ('8', '2011-02-28 01:58:41', '3', '4');
```

So:

**ORDER BY timestamp, sender** is useless

**ORDER BY sender, timestamp** is pretty ok, but it will not show older messages first

```
SELECT timestamp, sender, message FROM messages ORDER BY sender IN (SELECT DISTINCT sender FROM messages ORDER BY timestamp), timestamp;
```

does not work as i suppose it must work. And here is what i expected from this query (ofc is not what i get from this query :P):

```
+---------------------+--------+---------+
| timestamp           | sender | message |
+---------------------+--------+---------+
| 2011-02-28 01:58:24 |      3 | 1       |
| 2011-02-28 01:58:28 |      3 | 2       |
| 2011-02-28 01:58:38 |      3 | 3       |
| 2011-02-28 01:58:41 |      3 | 4       |
| 2011-02-28 01:58:35 |      1 | 5       |
| 2011-02-28 01:58:40 |      1 | 6       |
| 2011-02-28 01:58:36 |      2 | 7       |
| 2011-02-28 01:58:39 |      2 | 8       |
+---------------------+--------+---------+
```

Any ideas? links? tips? anything?
Thanks in advance, any questions are welcome

Comment: Could you state exactly what the query is supposed to achieve. You've said you want to do an irregular sort and give two examples that don't do what you want, but you don't describe what you actually want and trying to infer it from the table supplied is difficult.

Comment: last table is what i want to get, the result of the perfect query :D

Comment: just need to get all messages, grouped by sender, and sorted by timestamp, but not sorted by sender and timestamp

Comment: I think your going to need to add a column to capture the ordering information. This is basically the same question but with recursive queries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994716/how-to-preserve-order-of-children-to-appear-after-their-parents.

Comment: can't you just put in a specific sort order in your order by as in : order by sender asc, timestamp asc

Comment: nope, a1ex07's answer is just what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will it work for you `ORDER BY sender asc, timestamp desc` ?

**UPDATE**
  You probably need something like this:

```
SELECT a.timestamp, a.sender, a.message 
FROM messages a
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT b.sender_id, MIN(b.timestamp) as timestamp 
  FROM messages b GROUP BY sender
 )c ON (c.sender = a.sender)
ORDER BY c.timestamp, a.sender
```

Comment: nope, because sorting by sender ASC will not give me first messages timestamps, will give me first senders

Comment: I think the updated version is what you wanted (sorting by minimum timestamp, then by sender)

Comment: 1054 - Unknown column 'b.sender_id' in 'field list'

Comment: I meant `sender`. Sorry for misprint. changed

Comment: after removing those _id from query, the result is exactly what i was expect to see, Thank you!

Comment: just figured out that `ORDER BY c.timestamp, a.sender` must be in fact `ORDER BY c.timestamp, a.timestamp`. I had some problems with your ORDER BY clause with some subsequent LEFT JOINs on that query

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM messages ORDER BY sender, timestamp ASC;
```

Will sort by sender, then by timestamp giving you each senders data, sorted by timestamp. In MySQL when you use multiple sorts it just sorts by one, then the other.

What you are attempting to achieve is.. well, impossible, you cannot group the senders if they are not in order with the sender ideas.. what I've given is the closest you'll get in MySQL

Comment: ok, what about `SELECT * FROM countries ORDER by iso_code IN ('UK', 'US') desc, iso_code`, there are something like two sorts based on a single field... something like some favorites results. (query copied from [MySQL SELECT Syntax page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)